# How to connect a Python UnetSocket to an Agent that I have created using agentForService?

Tags: unetstack

I am trying to make a link between a Python script and a simulation running on UnetSim.
I want to send messages from Python and receive them in UnetStack using a *Python_Agent.groovy* that I created and added to container of each node in the simulation. I also want to do the reverse.

I used the fjage documentation (https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/fjage/dev/fjage.pdf) to help me. The problem is that in gateway class Services there is not the **PYTHON_AGENT** Service that I created. I can understand that as my enum Services does not modified class Services where there are NODE_INFO, PHYSICAL etc...
My question is then how the example in the documentation 1.6.3 works ? And is it applicable to my case ?

Here is my code :

**PythonSocketExample.py**

```
from unetpy import *
from fjagepy import *
import socket

node_address = '001'
host = socket.gethostname()

sock = UnetSocket(host, int(node_address) + 1100)
gw = sock.getGateway()

py_agent = gw.agentForService(Services.PYTHON_AGENT)
py_agent << DatagramReq(data = '$A001')
rsp = py_agent.receive()
print (rsp)
```

**UnetSimulation.groovy**

```
//! Simulation : Initialisation python

import org.arl.fjage.RealTimePlatform
import org.arl.fjage.*
import org.arl.unet.*
import org.arl.unet.phy.*
import org.arl.unet.sim.*
import org.arl.unet.sim.channels.*
import static org.arl.unet.Services.*
import static org.arl.unet.phy.Physical.*
//import java.net.ServerSocket

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// simulation settings

platform = RealTimePlatform           // use real-time mode

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// channel and modem settings

channel = [
  model:                ProtocolChannelModel,
  soundSpeed:           1500.mps,
  communicationRange:   3.km,
  interferenceRange:    3.km
]
modem.model = USMARTModem

modem.dataRate =        [640.bps, 6400.bps]
modem.frameLength =     [16.bytes, 64.bytes]
modem.powerLevel =      [0.dB, -10.dB]
modem.headerLength = 0
modem.preambleDuration = 0
modem.txDelay = 0

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// nodes settings and geometry

def beacons = 2..4          // 3 anchors from 2 to 4
def sensors = 5..104          // 100 sensors from 5 to 104
def nodeLocation = [:]

def D = 4000.m  // side of the simulation area
def L = 400.m  // distance between two node

nodeLocation[1] = [D/2-L, D/2 -L, -5.m]     //masterAnchor
nodeLocation[2] = [D/2+L, D/2 -L, -5.m]
nodeLocation[3] = [D/2, D/2+L, -5.m]
nodeLocation[4] = [D/2, D/2, -500.m]

sensors.each { myAddr ->
  nodeLocation[myAddr] = [rnd(0, D), rnd(0, D), rnd(-480.m, -500.m)]
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// simulation details

simulate {

  node '1', address: 1, location: nodeLocation[1], web: 8101, api: 1101, shell: true, stack: {
      container -> container.add 'py_agent' + 1, new Python_Agent()
  }

  beacons.each { myAddr ->
      def myNode = node("${myAddr}", address: myAddr, location: nodeLocation[myAddr], web: 8100 + myAddr , api: 1100 + myAddr, 
        stack: {container ->
  container.add 'py_agent' + myAddr, new Python_Agent()})
  }   

  sensors.each { myAddr ->
      def myNode = node("${myAddr}", address: myAddr, location: nodeLocation[myAddr], web: 8100 + myAddr, api: 1100 + myAddr,
        stack: {container ->
  container.add 'py_agent' + myAddr, new Python_Agent()})
  }
```

**Python_Agent.groovy**

```
import org.arl.fjage.*
import org.arl.unet.*

enum Services {
    PYTHON_AGENT
}

class Python_Agent extends UnetAgent {

    String fromNode;
    String toNode;
    String toClient;
    
    def nodeInfo;
    def myLocation;
    def myAddress;
    def phy;
    
    void setup() {
        register Services.PYTHON_AGENT
    }
    
    void startup() {
        // TODO
        nodeInfo = agentForService(Services.NODE_INFO)
        myLocation = nodeInfo.location
        myAddress = nodeInfo.address
        println('pyAgent ' + myAddress + ' works')
    }
  
    void processMessage(Message msg) {
    
        if (msg instanceof DatagramNtf /*&& msg.protocol == NODE_STATUS_PROTOCOL*/) { 

        println("Node "+ myAddress+ ' receiving ' + msg.text +' from ' + msg.from +" protocol is "+ msg.protocol)
        toNode = phy.energy
        
    }
  }
}
```

The first error that i get is :

```
1 error
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
C:\Users\mathi\OneDrive\Bureau\unet-3.0.0\FakeModem\python.groovy: 85: Enum constructor calls are only allowed inside the enum class
. At [85:50]  @ line 85, column 50.
   container.add 'py_agent' + 1, new Python
                                 ^
```

then if I comment the enum part and modifie the setup part, the simulation works

```
    void setup() {
        register 'PYTHON_AGENT'
    }
```

When I run PythonSocketExample.py, I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PythonSocketExample.py", line 11, in <module>
    py_agent = gw.agentForService(Services.PYTHON_AGENT)
AttributeError: type object 'Services' has no attribute 'PYTHON_AGENT'
```

The end of the log on UnetStack is here:

```
1582820223131   INFO    Python_Agent/84@1903:println    pyAgent 84 works
1582820223132   INFO    Python_Agent/39@1633:println    pyAgent 39 works
1582820415798   INFO    org.arl.unet.sim.SimulationMasterContainer@48:connected Incoming connection tcp:///137.195.214.230:1101//137.195.214.230.62913
1582820415875   INFO    org.arl.unet.sim.SimulationMasterContainer@2131:connectionClosed    Connection tcp:///137.195.214.230:1101//137.195.214.230.62913 closed
```

Thank you for your help

## **EDIT**

Thanks to your message and some research I am now able to send and receive message between UnetStack and Python by using MessageBehavior and GenericMessage.
I want my simulation to receive more than one message but as my   `add new MessageBehavior` is in startup() of my `PythonAgent.groovy` I need as much  `add new MessageBehavior` as message that I send.

I tested to put it on a processMessage(Message msg) but it seems this method does not recognize GenericMessage().

The question could be how to use MessageBehavior more than one time...
Here is my code :

### **`Python`**

**`ping_test.py`**

```
# Need to run the script two times. First time UnetStack don't get the Message
# I don't know where the bug come from

serport = serial.Serial()

## SET SELF ADDRESS
nodeID = '001'
nodeID_ping = '002'
command = b'$A' + nodeID.encode()
serport.write(command)

ack_msg = serport.readline()
print('ack_msg : ', ack_msg)

ping_command = b'$P' + nodeID_ping.encode()
serport.write(ping_command)

ack_msg = serport.readline()
print('ack_msg :', ack_msg)
rsp_msg = serport.readline()
print('rsp_msg :', rsp_msg)
```

**`FakeSerial_V2.py`**

```
from unetpy import *
import socket
import clientSocket

# a Serial class emulator
class Serial:

    ## init(): the constructor.  Many of the arguments have default values
    # and can be skipped when calling the constructor.
    def __init__( self, port='5000', baudrate = 19200, timeout=1, write_timeout=1,
                  bytesize = 8, parity = 'N', stopbits = 1, xonxoff=0,
                  rtscts = 0):

        self.last_instruction = ''
        self.nodeID = ''
        self.remote_nodeID = ''
        self.command = ''
        self._isOpen  = True
        self._receivedData = ''
        self._data = 'It was the best of times.\nIt was the worst of times.\n'
        self.phy = ''
        self.pySocket = ''
        
    ## write()
    # writes a string of characters to the Arduino
    def write( self, string):
        self.command = string.decode()
        _type = None
        print( 'FakeSerial got: ' + self.command)
        # SET_ADDRESS
        if (self.command[0:2] == '$A' and len(self.command) == 5):
            _type = 'set_address'
            self.nodeID = string[2:]
            self.pySocket = clientSocket.clientSocket(self.nodeID)  # initialize the clientSocket class
            self.pySocket.sendData(_type)    # need to fix the rsp Generic Message on UnetStack
            self.last_instruction = 'SET_ADDRESS_INSTRUCTION'
        # PING
        elif (self.command[0:2] == '$P' and len(self.command) == 5):
            _type = 'ping'
            to_addr = self.command[2:]
            # print(to_addr, type(to_addr))
            self.pySocket.sendData(_type, to_addr)
            self.last_instruction = "PING_INSTRUCTION"

        else:
            print("write FAILURE")
        
    
    ## readline()
    # reads characters from the fake Arduino until a \n is found.
    def readline( self ):
        self._receivedData = self.pySocket.receiveData()
        return self._receivedData
```

**`clientSocket.py`**

```
import socket
from unetpy import *
from fjagepy import *

class clientSocket:

    def __init__(self, nodeID = '001'):

        self.host = socket.gethostname()
        self.nodeID = int(nodeID)
        self.port = int(nodeID) + 1100
        self.sock = UnetSocket(self.host, self.port)
        self.gw = self.sock.getGateway()
        self.pyagent = 'pyagent' + str(self.nodeID)

    def sendData(self, _type, to_addr = '000' , data = 'None'):
        IDreq = 1

        # gmsg = GenericMessage(perf = Performative.REQUEST, recipient = pyagent)
        # gmsg.IDreq = IDreq
        # self.gw.send(gmsg)

        IDreq = IDreq + 1

        gmsg2 = GenericMessage(perf = Performative.REQUEST, recipient = self.pyagent)
        gmsg2.type = _type
        gmsg2.from_addr = self.nodeID
        gmsg2.to_addr = int(to_addr)
        gmsg2.data = data
        gmsg2.IDreq = IDreq
        self.gw.send(gmsg2)

        IDreq = 0

    def receiveData( self ):
        rgmsg = self.gw.receive(GenericMessage, 4000)
        print ('UnetStack state :', rgmsg.state)
        # print ('rsp :', rgmsg.data)
        # print('Ping time is', rgmsg.time_ping, 'ms')

        return rgmsg.data
```

### **`Groovy`**

**`sim1.groovy`**

```
import org.arl.fjage.RealTimePlatform

import org.arl.fjage.*
import org.arl.unet.*
import org.arl.unet.sim.channels.*

platform = RealTimePlatform           // use real-time mode

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// channel and modem settings

channel = [
  model:                ProtocolChannelModel,
  soundSpeed:           1500.mps,
  communicationRange:   3.km,
  interferenceRange:    3.km
]

modem.model = USMARTModem

modem.dataRate =        [640.bps, 6400.bps]
modem.frameLength =     [16.bytes, 64.bytes]
modem.powerLevel =      [0.dB, -10.dB]
modem.headerLength = 0
modem.preambleDuration = 0
modem.txDelay = 0

simulate {
    node '1', address: 1, web: 8101, api: 1101, stack: {
        container -> container.add 'pyagent1', new PythonAgent()
    }
    
    node '2', address: 2,location: [500.m ,500.m, -500.m], web: 8102, api: 1102, stack: {
        container -> container.add 'pyagent2', new PythonAgent()
    }
}
```

**`PythonAgent.groovy`**

```
import org.arl.fjage.*
import org.arl.unet.*
import org.arl.unet.phy.RxFrameNtf
import org.arl.unet.phy.TxFrameNtf

class PythonAgent extends UnetAgent {

    final static int PING_PROTOCOL = 10;
    final static int NODE_STATUS_PROTOCOL = 11;
    final static int BROADCAST_PROTOCOL = 12;
    final static int UNICAST_PROTOCOL = 13;
    final static int UNICAST_ACK_PROTOCOL = 14;
    final static int TEST_MSG_PROTOCOL = 15;
    final static int ECHO_PROTOCOL = 16;
    final static int QUALITY_PROTOCOL = 17;
    
    def nodeInfo;
    def phy;
    def myLocation;
    def myAddress;
    def IDreq = 0;
    def time_ping = null;
    def function_state = null;
    def data_to_py = null;

    void startup() {
        println(agentID.name + ' running')
        
    nodeInfo = agentForService Services.NODE_INFO
    phy = agentForService Services.PHYSICAL
    myLocation = nodeInfo.location
    myAddress = nodeInfo.address
    
    subscribe topic(phy)
    
    add new MessageBehavior(GenericMessage, { req ->
        println("In PythonAgent::MessageBehavior req ="+req)
        if (req.performative) println("req.performative is " + req.performative)
        else println("req.performative is null")

        def ack = new GenericMessage(req, Performative.INFORM)
        def rsp = new GenericMessage(req, Performative.INFORM)
        println('IDreq = ' + req.IDreq)
      
        if ((req.performative == Performative.REQUEST) && (req.IDreq == 2)) {
            // IDreq = req.IDreq
            // println('IDreq = ' + IDreq)
            //log.info "Generic message request of type ${req.type}"
            function_state = 'None';
            data_to_py = 'None';
            
            switch (req.type) {
                case 'set_address':
                    println("Handling set_address")
                    ack.state = "Handling set_address"
                    ack.data = '#A' + corrected_address(myAddress);
                    send ack;
                    rsp.data = ack.data; break;
            }
        }
    })
    
    add new MessageBehavior(GenericMessage, { req ->
        println("In PythonAgent::MessageBehavior req ="+req)
        if (req.performative) println("req.performative is " + req.performative)
        else println("req.performative is null")

        def ack = new GenericMessage(req, Performative.INFORM)
        def rsp = new GenericMessage(req, Performative.INFORM)
        println('IDreq = ' + req.IDreq)
      
        if ((req.performative == Performative.REQUEST) && (req.IDreq == 2)) {
            // IDreq = req.IDreq
            // println('IDreq = ' + IDreq)
            //log.info "Generic message request of type ${req.type}"
            function_state = 'None';
            data_to_py = 'None';
            
            switch (req.type) {
                case 'set_address':
                    println("Handling set_address")
                    ack.state = "Handling set_address"
                    ack.data = '#A' + corrected_address(myAddress);
                    send ack;
                    rsp.data = ack.data; break;
                case 'loc':
                    //println("Handling localisation request");
                    sendUPSBeacon(); break;
                case 'ping':
                    println("Handling ping request");
                    ack.state = "Handling ping request"; ack.data = '$P' + corrected_address(req.to_addr);
                    send ack;
                    ping(req.to_addr);
                    rsp.time_ping = time_ping; break;
                case 'exe':
                    //println("Handling exe request"); 
                    exe(); break;
                case 'sense':
                    //println("Handling sense request"); 
                    sense(); break;
                default: println "Unknown request";
            }
            //println "In USMARTBaseAnchorDaemon::MessageBehavior, just after exe"
            
            rsp.state = function_state
            
            rsp.data = data_to_py
            println "In PythonAgent::MessageBehavior, rsp is " + rsp     
            send rsp
        }
    })

    }
    
    void ping(to_addr) {

        println "Pinging ${to_addr} at ${nanoTime()}"

        DatagramReq req = new DatagramReq(to: to_addr, protocol: PING_PROTOCOL)
        phy << req
        def txNtf = receive(TxFrameNtf, 10000) // TO-DO:check protocol
        def rxNtf = receive({ it instanceof RxFrameNtf && it.from == req.to}, 10000)
        if (txNtf && rxNtf && rxNtf.from == req.to) {
            time_ping = (rxNtf.rxTime-txNtf.txTime)/1000 //in ms
            println("Response from ${rxNtf.from}: ")
            println("rxTime=${rxNtf.rxTime}")
            println("txTime=${txNtf.txTime}")
            println("Response from ${rxNtf.from}: time = ${time_ping}ms")
            function_state = 'Ping processed'
            data_to_py = "#R" + corrected_address(to_addr) + 'T' + rxNtf.data
        }
        else {
            function_state = 'Ping Request timeout'
            println (function_state)
            
        }
        
    }
    
    @Override
    void processMessage(Message msg) {
        // pong
        if (msg instanceof DatagramNtf && msg.protocol == PING_PROTOCOL) {
            println("pong : Node "+ myAddress + ' from ' + msg.from +" protocol is "+ msg.protocol)
            send new DatagramReq(recipient: msg.sender, to: msg.from, data: phy.energy as byte[], protocol: PING_PROTOCOL)
            println ('processMessage energy : ' + phy.energy)
        }
    }
    
    String corrected_address(address) {
        address = address.toString()
        if (address.size() == 1) address = '00' + address
        if (address.size() == 2) address = '0' + address
        return address
    }
}
```

**`USMARTModem.groovy`**

```
import org.arl.fjage.Message
import org.arl.unet.sim.HalfDuplexModem

import org.arl.fjage.*
import org.arl.unet.*
import org.arl.unet.phy.*
import org.arl.unet.sim.*
import org.arl.unet.sim.channels.*
import static org.arl.unet.Services.*
import static org.arl.unet.phy.Physical.*

/*

Ptx=  V*Itx //power consumed in transmission in watt
    Prx = V*Irx //power consumed in receiving packets in watt
    Etx = Math.floor(avgSent)*(Ptx*0.3675)
    energyAll =  (Math.floor(avgSent)*(Ptx*0.3675)) + (Math.floor(avgReceived)*(Prx*0.3675)) // total energy consumed for all the packets sent and received throughout the simulation
   // EtxSubset = Math.floor(avgTxCountNs)*(Ptx*0.3675) // energy consumed in transmitiing 25% of packets in Joul
    bytesDelivered = Math.floor(avgReceived)* modem.frameLength[1]
    JPerBit = energyAll/(bytesDelivered * 8)

*/
//Duration of data packet in seconds = data packet size (in bits)/bandwidth (in bps) = (15*8)/50000 = 0.0024


class USMARTModem extends HalfDuplexModem {

  static final def txPower = -17.dB
  static final def acousticDataRate = 640.bps
  static final def payLoadSize = 5.bytes
  static final def headerDuration = (30+75+200)/1000  //in seconds --> in our case nanomodem v3 provides us with the header (in ms) to add to the actual payload in the frame length.. refer to the modem datasheet
  static final def V = 5 // supply voltage in volt
  static final def Itx = 0.3, Irx = 0.005, Iidle =  0.0025 //current in Am
  
  float payLoadDuration = (payLoadSize*8)/acousticDataRate //in seconds
  float dataPacketDuration = payLoadDuration +headerDuration //in seconds
  float energy = 2000 //initial energy in Joule
  float test = energy+1
  float Ptx = V*Itx, Prx=V*Irx, Pidle = V*Iidle //power in watt
  float totalEtx =0
  float totalErx =0
  float totalEidle =0
  float totalEnergyConsumed =0 
  float Etx = Ptx * dataPacketDuration //Energy in Joul
  float Erx = Prx * dataPacketDuration
  float Eidle = Pidle * dataPacketDuration
  
  
     
 // float power = 0.00001995262315 //in watt (-17 in db=10log(p/1mw)  .. so p = 10to the power -1.7  = 0.00001995262315
 // BigDecimal Ptx = (Math.pow(10.0,(txPower/10) ))/1000 //????
 // BigDecimal Etx= Ptx *((frameLength[1]*8)/640) // This is consumed energy (in transmission) Etx = Ptx*time it takes to tramsnit tha packet
 //float Etx =10
  
   
  @Override
  boolean send(Message m) {
    if (m instanceof TxFrameNtf)
        {
          energy -= Etx// Remaining energy
          totalEtx += Etx  //total energy consumed in tx
        }
    if (m instanceof  RxFrameNtf) 
        {
          energy -= Erx   // Remaining energy
          totalErx += Erx  //total energy consumed in rx
         }
       
    if(!busy) 
     { 
       energy-= Eidle //Remaining energy
       totalEidle += Eidle //total energy consumed while Eidle
     } 
     
     
     totalEnergyConsumed = totalEtx+totalErx+totalEidle
    return super.send(m)
  }
      
}
```

Sorry for the very very long post...I think everything was necessary to understand the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few problems in your original code:

1. You don't need to create a service, since you can address the agent by its name. This should be sufficient for your example here.
2. To process a request (`DatagramReq` from your Python code), you should override the `processRequest()` method in the agent.

Here's a simplified example based on your original code:

**`PythonAgent.groovy`:**

```java
import org.arl.fjage.*
import org.arl.unet.*

class PythonAgent extends UnetAgent {

    void startup() {
        println('pyAgent running')
    }

    @Override
    Message processRequest(Message msg) {
        if (msg instanceof DatagramReq) { 
            println('Got a DatagramNtf')
            // do whatever you want with the request
            return new Message(msg, Performative.AGREE)
        }
        return null
    }
}
```

**`sim1.groovy`**:

```java
import org.arl.fjage.RealTimePlatform

platform = RealTimePlatform           // use real-time mode

simulate {
    node '1', address: 1, web: 8101, api: 1101, stack: {
        container -> container.add 'pyagent', new PythonAgent()
    }
}
```

and **`test1.py`**:

```py
from unetpy import *
from fjagepy import *

sock = UnetSocket('localhost', 1101)   # node 1's API port as per sim script
gw = sock.getGateway()
pyagent = gw.agent('pyagent')          # agent name as per sim script
rsp = pyagent << DatagramReq()
print(rsp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I did not knew I needed to @Override. I still have a question, how can I put data in my DatagramReq that I can extract in UnetStack ? 
 I tried this as a first solution looking at the Handbook but it doesn't works..

**`PythonAgent.groovy`**

```
import org.arl.fjage.*
import org.arl.unet.*

class PythonAgent extends UnetAgent {

    void startup() {
        println('pyAgent running')
    }

    @Override
    Message processRequest(Message msg) {
        if (msg instanceof DatagramReq) { 
            println('Got a DatagramNtf')
            println(msg.data)
            // do whatever you want with the request
            return new Message(msg, Performative.AGREE)
        }
        return null
    }
}
```

**`test1.py`**

```
from unetpy import *
from fjagepy import *

sock = UnetSocket('localhost', 1101)   # node 1's API port as per sim script
gw = sock.getGateway()
pyagent = gw.agent('pyagent')         # agent name as per sim script
rsp1 = pyagent << DatagramReq( data = [42])
rsp2 = pyagent << DatagramReq( data = 'data_string')
print(rsp1, rsp2)
```

On the Python terminal I will get **`Agree None`**. I can transmit an array but not a string ?

The log print

```
Incoming connection tcp:///127.0.0.1:1101//127.0.0.1.51208
1583166206032   INFO    PythonAgent/1@2643:println  Got a DatagramNtf
1583166206032   INFO    PythonAgent/1@2643:println  [B@4e3d88df
1583166206033   WARNING org.arl.fjage.remote.ConnectionHandler@2670:run Bad JSON request: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 5f in {"action": "send", "relay": true, "message": { "clazz": "org.arl.unet.DatagramReq", "data": {"msgID":"492ac9dd-c2bf-4c0c-9198-3b32fb416f33","perf":"REQUEST","recipient":"pyagent","sender":"PythonGW-c8e66e0f-b5d5-433b-bfa9-09be708ab4c9","inReplyTo":null,"data":"data_string"} }}
1583166207081   INFO    org.arl.unet.sim.SimulationMasterContainer@2670:connectionClosed    Connection tcp:///127.0.0.1:1101//127.0.0.1.51208 closed
```

**`[B@4e3d88df`** correspond to **`[42]`**  but I don't know how to decode it. And in fact I am more interested in sending string than array. I have a track about using PDU but how could it works with Python ?

Comment: You don't _need_ to `@Override`. It is just good practice so that the compiler warns you if you happened to misspell the method name, and for a reader to quickly understand that this is a method that the superclass defines.

Comment: You can send a byte array: `DatagramReq(data=b"data_string")` and get back the data from the `DatagramNtf` as `bytes(ntf.data)`. To convert byte arrays to/from strings, you can use `encode()` and `decode()`: see https://www.journaldev.com/23500/python-string-to-bytes-to-string

Comment: Ok, I already tried to convert my data into bytes but when i do that i get the error
```return _json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
  File "C:\Users\mathi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable```

Comment: Strange, as I don't seem to able to reproduce the issue. What version of `unetpy` and `fjagepy` are you on? Anyway, you can also try wrapping the byte array into a list: `DatagramReq(data=list(b"data_string"))`

Comment: I have the ```unetpy 3.0.3``` and ```fjagepy 1.6.1``` versions